# Recursive method gets stuck on first leaf node php

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a problem with a recursive search. This recursive function navigates the object up to the first leaf and seems to ignore recursion.

### Function Call

```
$node = $this->_find_recursive($staff, "user_id", 681); // $staff is the json_decoded of "Source Data" (see below)
```

This should return the "James Anderson" node since it has the user_id = 681 but the function never reach that node. What is wrong here? I will appreciate your help. Thanks!

### Output

root 0 681
Company 0 681
Super User 670 681
Michael Smith 671 681
Christopher Johnson 672 681

### Method

```
private function _find_recursive($node, $key, $value)
    {
            echo " ". " ". $node->name. " ". $node->$key. " ". $value . "\n";
            if($node->$key == $value)
            {
                    return $node;
            }
            else
            {
                    foreach($node->children as $cur_node)
                    {        
                            return $this->_find_recursive($cur_node, $key, $value);
                    }
            }
            return NULL;
    }
```

### Source Data

```
{
"text": ".",
"name": "root",
"user_id": 0,
"children": [
    {
        "user_id": 0,
        "name": "Company",
        "staff_profile" : "company",
        "children": [
            {
                "user_id": 670,
                "name": "Super User",
                "staff_profile" : "ceo",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "user_id": 671,
                        "name": "Michael Smith",
                        "staff_profile" : "manager",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "user_id": 672,
                                "name": "Christopher Johnson",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            },{
                                "user_id": 675,
                                "name": "Daniel Brown",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "user_id": 676,
                        "name": "David Davis",
                        "staff_profile" : "manager",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "user_id": 677,
                                "name": "Andrew Miller",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            },{
                                "user_id": 678,
                                "name": "Justin Wilson",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "user_id": 681,
                "name": "James Anderson",
                "staff_profile" : "ceo",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "user_id": 682,
                        "name": "Nicholas Tomas",
                        "staff_profile" : "manager",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "user_id": 683,
                                "name": "Joseph Jackson",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "user_id": 687,
                        "name": "Kyle Thompson",
                        "staff_profile" : "manager",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "user_id": 688,
                                "name": "Brandon Garcia",
                                "staff_profile" : "representative",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thanks Phil. Can you explain me more?

Comment: I changed my comment into an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unchecked `return` in your `foreach` loop is the problem. You're basically exiting the loop on the first iteration. Try this instead...

```
foreach($node->children as $cur_node) {
    if ($check = $this->_find_recursive($cur_node, $key, $value)) {
        return $check;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jorge You're welcome. Beware recursive functions; on that path lies madness ;)